# wordpress media library keeps spinning on server but working on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am facing issue on wordpress media library. When i try to uploading images image has uploaded successfully but it shows "Please try again later" message and keep spinning image not loaded. Already existing image also not loaded. Please advise on this. This issue only on server. I keep the same file on local and working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAG9I.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does your error log say? Are their errors in your browser console?

Comment: In console we can see this message {"wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1579586973}

Comment: Also admin-ajax.php file keep refresh and getting {"rest_nonce":"5890ac1e3f","heartbeat_nonce":"791862d37b","wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1579608685} this response

Comment: Those aren't errors. Check server error logs as well and set your console to view errors.

Comment: Thanks and I will check let you know what happened